# gatsby build - Building static HTML for pages failed, error : "WebpackError: ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined"

Tags: firebase, gatsby

I have a problem while running `gatsby build` at the **Building static html step**.  I'm working with gatsby for the frontend and firebase for the backend.  I have this error :

```
ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


 85 | ]);
 86 | 
>    87 | proxyRequestMethods(Index, '_index', IDBIndex, [
    | ^
 88 |   'get',
 89 |   'getKey',
 90 |   'getAll',


 WebpackError: ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined
```

I think the problem comes from my firebase.js file, because when i comment it, the error no longer appears.  Here it is :

```
import firebase from "firebase"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDCiX9_kFYoatKJB7Idc-K_k2XrkwUs5So",
  authDomain: "gourmeto-6fd67.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://gourmeto-6fd67.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "gourmeto-6fd67",
  storageBucket: "gourmeto-6fd67.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "208164789511",
  appId: "1:208164789511:web:22745f19a559f32a"
};


  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

  /*export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
  export const facebookProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
  export const auth = firebase.auth()*/


  /*export const signOut = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut()
  }*/

  export default firebase
```

Thanks for yours answers !

Comment: What is `IDBIndex`?

Comment: It's actually a part of my question because i can't find an explanation on the web

Comment: The error has occured in this file : **node_modules/idb/lib/idb.mjs**

Comment: Getting the same error, have tried multiple related solutions, but nothing seems to be working so far :(

Answer (score 1):

During SSR "browser globals" like `window`, `document`, or `IDBIndex` are undefined. Only browser runtime can truly understand these, as well as, they can hold state specific to currently running page.

To fix you need to ensure code accessing "globals" is not running during build. If it is third-party lib, you can replace that module with empty module.

Here is simplistic example of using gatsby with firebase auth:

**1. Replace firebase module with empty module during SSR.**

```
// gatsby-node.js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /@firebase/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

**2. Do not use directly firebase code** eg. use lazy approach

```
// firebase-wrapper.js
import firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseConfig = {...}

const lazy = (fn) => {
  let isLoaded = false
  let result
  return () => {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      isLoaded = true
      result = fn()
    }
    return result
  }
}

const app = lazy(() => firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig))
const auth = lazy(() => app().auth())
const GoogleAuthProvider = lazy(() => new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())

export { app, auth, GoogleAuthProvider }
```

**3. Make sure it is called in browser**, eg. useEffect, buttonAction, stateInitialization, customProvider or customHook etc

```
// index.js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import {auth, GoogleAuthProvider} from "../firebase-wrapper.js"

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(()=>{
    return auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser)
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <div>User:{user && user.uid}</div>
      <button onClick={()=>auth().signInWithPopup(GoogleAuthProvider())}>Sing in with Google</button>
      <button onClick={()=>auth().signOut()}>Sign out</button>
   </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

There are more approaches to lazy loading like react-loadable, dynamic/lazy imports etc.

See reference [Gatsby Docs - Debugging HTML builds](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, browser globals are not available during build.

Simply checking for `window` before declaring `firebase` worked for me:

```js
let firebase;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  firebase = require('firebase');
}
```

**EDIT: not quite (works in some cases but fell short once my app got more complex)**

I suggest following this post: [Firebase and Gatsby, Together At Last](https://kyleshevlin.com/firebase-and-gatsby-together-at-last).